# Access VBA Last update on client

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, vba

A friend of mine asked me to help him with a problem in Access.
He has a costumers list that stores some info in the tables such as name, adress, ....

The here is also a column with the options "Last update"

Now the thing that i"m trying to figure out is how to show a msgbox witht the clients name when the "last update" value is bigger than a month.

So far i have the code shown below:

```
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

'SQL = "SELECT * FROM Beheer WHERE " & Me.[Last update] & " >= (" & Date & " - INTERVAL 1 Month)"
'SQL = "SELECT * FROM Beheer WHERE DateDiff(" & "m" & "," & Me.[Last update] & "," & Date & ") <= 1"

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
If RS.EOF Then
  MsgBox "No batch ID found.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Last Batch"
Else
  MsgBox "Last batch ID is " & RS![Customer name] & ".", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Customer To update"
End If
RS.Close
DB.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing
```

As you can see I commented the two SQL Queries cause the form a error I cant get passed .

Could someone help me pleas ?

Best regards

Comment: Be careful how you describe this issue... do you really mean "select record if last update is greater than 30 days"? Selecting based on being a different month can result in your getting a record updated on 1/31/2015.

Comment: No actualy what i want to do is that it will popup a message box that displays the company name where from the "Last update" date is older than a month. , actualy sounds simple but i cant get it done :s

Comment: First, you don't mention where your code is located, so makes it tougher to know what you want. Second, do you realize your code will only show the FIRST record because you never loop through your recordset? Last, as I asked before, what is your definition of a month? 30 days or more? Month < current month?

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Beheer WHERE DateDiff('m',[Last update] , Date()) >= 1"
```

explanation:
this would get you only the records that number of month passed is equl or gratter than 1....

the function DateDiff need to be part of the query - not part of the code as you wrote it....

what you wrote:

```
Me.[Last update]
```

make the code searh a control on the form that is name is "Last update"

hope i help you.

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?